# How to modify a already made tween?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a tween like this :

```
new Tween(myObject, "x",null,nowPosition,finalPosition,time,true);
sometween.start();
```

Now when the tween has not finished and is somewhere in the middle and the final position changes. I want this tween to be modified so instead of moving to its already defined postion the object goes to the final position. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, but the lazy thing that comes to mind is using the [continueTo()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#continueTo()) method, assuming you're using [fl.transition.Tween](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html).

e.g.:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;

var nowPosition:Number = 0;
var finalPosition:Number = 200;
var time:int = 3;
var sometween:Tween = new Tween(myObject, "x",null,nowPosition,finalPosition,time,true);
sometween.start();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, update);

function update(event:MouseEvent):void {
    sometween.continueTo(mouseX,.2);
}
```

HTH,
George